# Ways to arrange couples

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many non-negative integer solutions are there for the following?

> $$a + b + c = 5$$

From my understanding, the answer would be:

> $$\frac {7!}{5!\cdot 2!} = 21$$

I tried applying the same principle to the question below.

> There are 5 married couples. How many ways can we arrange them in a line if none of the husbands are next to each other?

**Method 1**

Let $H$ represent a husband and $W$ represent a wife.

Thus, the 5 couples can be arranged in the following manner:

> $$\text {_} \; W_1 \; \text {_} \; W_2 \; \text {_} \; W_3 \; \text {_} \; W_4 \; \text {_} \; W_5 \; \text {_}$$

The _ represents a position where a husband can be placed.

The wives can be arranged in $5!$ ways.

There are 6 positions that $H_1$ could take, 5 positions that $H_2$ could take, 4 positions that $H_3$ could take, and so on, which leads to $6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2 = 720$ total ways to arrange the husbands.

Thus, the answer is $5!\cdot 720 = 86400$ ways to arrange the 5 couples.

**Method 2**

Looking back at the following:

> $$\text {_} \; W_1 \; \text {_} \; W_2 \; \text {_} \; W_3 \; \text {_} \; W_4 \; \text {_} \; W_5 \; \text {_}$$

If each _, of which there are 6 in total, represents a variable such that $a + b + c + d + e + f = 5$, there would be $\frac {10!}{5!}$ ways to arrange the 5 husbands.

This leads to a total of $\frac {10!}{5!} \cdot 5! = 10! = 3628800$ ways to arrange the 5 couples.

**Why is the second method incorrect?**

Comment: When placing dividers, they can be next to one another. This is not the same as requiring the husbands sit apart (wives can never sit as $W_1W_2W_3$ in your example, but it is possible for $a=b=c=0$ in $a+b+c+d+e+f=5$). I believe this is the discrepancy.

Comment: I counted $21$ options, so I think that your initial answer of $\frac{7!}{5!2!}$ is correct.